# is using std::regex for simple RX is good practice?

Tags: c++, regex

For example, my situation:
I'm getting an input of "0", "1", "true" or "false". (in any case)
what is preferred on terms of performance, code reading, any basically best-practice:

```
bool func(string param)
{
    string lowerCase = param;
    to_lower(lowerCase);
    if (lowerCase == "0" || lowerCase == "false")
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (lowerCase == "1" || lowerCase == "true")
    {
        return true;
    }
    throw ....
}
```

or:

```
bool func(string param)
{
    string lowerCase = param;
    to_lower(lowerCase);
    regex rxTrue  ("1|true");
    regex rxFalse ("0|false");

    if (regex_match(lowerCase, rxTrue)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (regex_match(lowerCase, rxFalse)
    {
        return false;
    }
    throw ....
}
```

Comment: For the regex, there should be a flag telling it not to be case sensitive, so you don't have to convert it to lower-case. Other than that I think the explicit checking is, well, more explicit and easier to read,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is somewhat clearer, and easier to extend (e.g.: accepting
`"yes"` and `"no"`, or prefixes, with `"1|t(?:rue)?)"` and
`"0|f(?:alse)?"`.  With regards to performance, the second can (and
should) be made significantly faster by declaring the `regex` `static`
(and `const`, while you're at it), e.g.:

```
static regex const rxTrue ( "1|true" , regex_constants::icase );
static regex const rxFalse( "0|false", regex_constants::icase );
```

Note too that by specifying case insensitivity, you'll not have to
convert the input to lower case.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a hunch, but probably the first one is going to be faster (no regex-compiling involved). Also, the second version depends on your compiler supporting the C++11 `<regex>` implementation, so depending on the environments you need to support, the second option is ruled out automatically.